# How do I shallow test a react component wrapped in memo and withStyles?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, enzyme, memo

I have a component which is wrapped in both a Material-UI `withStyles` HOC and a React `memo` HOC.

I am unable to test this component as I am unable to call `dive()`:

`ShallowWrapper::dive() can only be called on components`

The only option I am currently aware of is to independently `export Demo` and `export default withStyles(styles)(Demo)`. This allows me to test the component that isn't wrapped in `withStyles`. I would like to avoid this method.

If I remove memo(), I am able to test the component. Likewise, if I remove withStyles(), I am also able to test the component. The combination of these HOCs render my component un-testable.

What are some available strategies to effectively test this component?

**demo.js**

```
import React, { memo } from "react";
import MUIIconButton from "@material-ui/core/IconButton";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Tooltip from "@material-ui/core/Tooltip";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";

const styles = () => ({
  root: {
    backgroundColor: "red"
    /* more styles... */
  }
});

const Demo = memo(({ label, classes }) => (
  <div className={classes.root}>
    <Tooltip disableFocusListener title={label}>
      <Typography>label</Typography>
    </Tooltip>
  </div>
));

export default withStyles(styles)(Demo);
```

**demo.test.js**

```
import React from "react";
import Adapter from "enzyme-adapter-react-16";
import { configure, shallow } from "enzyme";
import Demo from "./demo";
import MUIIconButton from "@material-ui/core/IconButton";
import Tooltip from "@material-ui/core/Tooltip";

configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

describe("Demo", () => {
  it("Should have a tooltip with label", () => {
    const tooltip = "My tooltip";

    const el = shallow(<Demo label={tooltip} />).dive();

    expect(el.find(Tooltip).props().title).toEqual(tooltip);
  });
});
```

**Full working Sandbox**

[image: Edit 2j3o14zxy0]

Comment: check https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/9266 - there is some workaround with `createShallow`. But I'd rather keep using separate export as you already do. It's more reliable way. In some cases like Redux-connected components it's like official suggestion. So would not it be better to use the same approach across different components?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As skyboyer suggests, you should just `export` the memoized function. You can `import` the default export `HOC` and utilize `mount`, but you'll need to mock the `classes` object to match how it's being used within the component.

**Working example**: https://codesandbox.io/s/4r492qvoz9

**components/Demo/demo.js**

```
import React, { memo } from "react";
import MUIIconButton from "@material-ui/core/IconButton";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Tooltip from "@material-ui/core/Tooltip";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";

const styles = () => ({
  root: {
    backgroundColor: "red"
    /* more styles... */
  }
});

export const Demo = memo(({ label, classes }) => {
  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <Tooltip disableFocusListener title={label}>
        <Typography>label</Typography>
      </Tooltip>
    </div>
  );
});

export default withStyles(styles)(Demo);
```

**components/Demo/__tests__/demo.test.js** if ever need to see the `DOM` structure, then just use `console.log(wrapper.debug());` -- for example `console.log(mountHOComponent.debug());`)

```
import React from "react";
import Adapter from "enzyme-adapter-react-16";
import { configure, shallow, mount } from "enzyme";
import { Demo } from "../demo";
import HOCDemo from "../demo";

configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

const initialProps = {
  label: "My tooltip",
  classes: {
    root: "component-example"
  }
};

const shallowWrapper = shallow(<Demo {...initialProps} />);
const mountWrapper = mount(<Demo {...initialProps} />);
const mountHOComponent = mount(<HOCDemo {...initialProps} />);

describe("Demo", () => {
  afterAll(() => {
    shallowWrapper.unmount();
    mountWrapper.unmount();
  });

  it("shallowWrap renders a tooltip with label", () => {
    expect(shallowWrapper.find("WithStyles(Tooltip)").props().title).toBe(
      initialProps.label
    );
  });

  it("mountWrap renders a tooltip with label", () => {
    expect(mountWrapper.find("Tooltip").props().title).toBe(initialProps.label);
  });

  it("mountHOComponent renders a tooltip with label", () => {
    expect(mountHOComponent.find("Tooltip").props().title).toBe(
      initialProps.label
    );
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, we have decided to bite the bullet and go with this approach and it's working well. But I still don't really know why a shallow(el).dive().dive() (One dive per HOC rule) didn't work as expected.

Answer (score 10):

When I wrap with memo, I get a shape that looks like this

```
import MemoizedFoo from './Foo'
console.log(MemoizedFoo) 

    { '$$typeof': Symbol(react.memo),
      type:
       { [Function: Foo]
         displayName: 'Foo',
         defaultProps: { theme: {} } },
      compare: null }
```

so in my jest test, i can get the inner component by referencing the type key

```
import MemoizedFoo from './Foo'
const Foo = MemoizedFoo.type

describe() { it() { shallow(Foo) ...etc } }
```

This is great for shallow unit tests.

If i was mounting a parent component and looking for children to be present, you could do something like this:

```
wrapper = mount(Layout)
wrapper.find('Memo(Foo)')
```

Answer (score 0):

This is now fixed as of [enzyme-adapter-react-16 v1.13.0](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/commit/991b26e0d7c66550c3b403e22f5b47e5bc3a5482), which added memo dive() support. Here is a forked sandbox with the dependency updated to show that both of the test methods (dive and export workaround) now pass.

[image: Edit Testing Composed Memo and withStyles]